# Como localizar todos os caracteres '>' de um memo e armazenar em um vetor utilizando delphi?

Tags: array, delphi

Tenho um campo `edit` no `Delphi` e preciso percorrê-lo em busca do caractere `>` e armazenar a posição de todos os caracteres `>` em um vetor.
Fazendo da seguinte forma eu consigo pegar a posição apenas do primeiro caractere `>` no `memo`, porém preciso pegar a posição de todos.

```
Texto := memdsformapreparo.Text;
posicao := memdsformapreparo.SelStart; //pega posição do clique
posicaofinal := memdsformapreparo.SelLength; //pega posição final do mouse
posicaoabre := AnsiPos('<', Texto); //pega posição do caractere maior
posicaofecha:= AnsiPos('>', Texto); //pega posição do caractere menor

{if ((posicaoabre <= posicao) and (posicaofecha > posicao)) or ((posicaofinal >= posicaoabre) or (posicaofinal <= posicaofecha)) then
begin
  memdsformapreparo.SelStart := posicaofecha;
end;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode-se fazer assim:

```
var
  i, len: integer;
  posicoes: array of integer;
  texto: string;
begin
  texto := 'conteúdo > do > texto';
  SetLength(posicoes, 0);        //esvaziar array na inicialização
  for i := 1 to length(texto) do
    if texto[i] = '>' then
    begin
      len := Length(posicoes);
      SetLength(posicoes, len + 1);
      posicoes[len] := i;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Para ficar menos verboso no If faria assim SetLength(posicoes, Length(posicoes) + 1);
posicoes[Length(posicoes) - 1] := i;

Comment: consegui fazer da seguinte forma:
while(a <= Length(Texto)) do
     begin
          c := copy(Texto, a, 1);
          if (c = '>') then
          begin
               maior[nmaior] := a;
               nmaior := nmaior+1;
          end;

          if (c = '<') then
          begin
               menor[nmenor] := a;
               nmenor := nmenor+1;
          end;
          a := a+1;
     end;

Answer (score 3):

Para você pegar a posição de todos os caracteres `>` na `string` e armazenar em um `array`, seria assim:

```
var
  posicao: Integer;
  posicoes: Array of Integer;
  texto: String;
begin
  while (Pos('>', texto) > 0) do // Verifica se tem '>' na variável texto
  begin
    SetLength(posicoes, Length(posicoes) + 1); // Aumenta um espaço no array
    posicao := Pos('>', texto); // Pega a posição do primeiro >
    posicoes[High(posicoes)] := posicao; // Armazena a posição no ultimo espaço do array
    texto[posicao] := ' '; // Substitui o > por espaço
  end;

  // Neste ponto você terá todas as posições dos '>' dentro do array posicoes
end;
```

Veja mais sobre a função `POS` [aqui](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_Pos@RawByteString@RawByteString.html).

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/RgH5jI).